Ktor HttpResponse setCookies() only returns one cookie even though others are also available
Im currently trying to authenticate with an api, and need to get some set cookies. In inspect element I can see the set-cookies that I need as attached:

However my code only returns the cookie related to "datadome", but I need all of them. My code is here:
val client = HttpClient()

class LoginConnection {
    suspend fun login(
        email: String,
        password: String,
        onCookieReceived: suspend  (List<Cookie>?) -> Unit
    ){
        val res = client.submitForm(
            url =  "https://users.premierleague.com/accounts/login/",
            formParameters = parameters {
                append("login", email)
                append("password", password)
                append("app", "plfpl-web")
                append("redirect-uri", "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/")
            }
        ) {
            headers {
                append(HttpHeaders.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
                append(HttpHeaders.AcceptLanguage, "en")
            }
            method = HttpMethod.Post
        }
        val cookie = res.setCookie()
        println(cookie)
        try {
            onCookieReceived(
                cookie
            )
        }catch (e: Exception){
            onCookieReceived(null)
        }
    }
}


According to the code, the HttpMessage.setCookie method returns all cookies extracted from all Set-Cookie headers. So the problem is most likely in something else.

@AlekseiTirman Do you have any pointers to where I should go?

Can you share the complete HTTP response as text?
